# Updating a @State var in SwiftUI from an async method doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, async-await

I have the following View:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var data = [SomeClass]()

    var body: some View {
        List(data, id: \.self) { item in
            Text(item.someText)
        }
    }

    func fetchDataSync() {
        Task.detached {
            await fetchData()
        }
    }

    @MainActor
    func fetchData() async {
        let data = await SomeService.getAll()
        self.data = data
        print(data.first?.someProperty)
        // > Optional(115)
        print(self.data.first?.someProperty)
        // > Optional(101)
    }
}
```

now the method `fetchDataSync` is a delegate that gets called in a sync context whenever there is new data. I've noticed that the views don't change so I've added the printouts. You can see the printed values, which differ. How is this possible? I'm in a MainActor, and I even tried detaching the task. Didn't help. Is this a bug?

It should be mentioned that the objects returned by getAll are created inside that method and not given to any other part of the code. Since they are class objects, the value might be changed from elsewhere, but if so both references should still be the same and not produce different output.

My theory is that for some reason the state just stays unchanged. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Making a method that does wait as main actor does not seems very good : it could bloc your main thread. On the self.data = data would be in an dispatch main ´ to update the state var.

Comment: @PtitXav the await does not block the main thread. every async method is always executed on the actor it should be executed on. SomeService is an actor that does not run on the main thread. A surprising fact about Swift Concurrency that took me a while to wrap my head around. This code never blocks the main thread

Comment: Thank you for the feedback @malhal. How would you have written a method that sets the state to an outside data source?

Comment: `.task { data = await fetchData() }` where data is an array of structs

Comment: the problem is that this would only happen once. `fetchDataSync` is a method that's passed as a listener to any data changing inside the service. this could be done with environment objects, but those would be overkill for a list that's only ever used in this one spot and only changed through one method. @malhal

Comment: `.task(id: someStateThatChanges) { resultsState = await fetchData(someStateThatChanges) }`

Comment: @malhal at that point the code isn't too different. I put the setting of resultsState in a separate method for debugging. This method can also be shortened to `self.data  = await SomeService.getAll()`. I just split the lines to make the bug here more apparent. Lastly, the reason why I'm not setting the stuff directly but wrapping it in a sync method is because I'm using a library that's executing a listener whenever the data changed. this listener does not support concurrency. so the task(id) method would only work with another helper that sets the id, making the code longer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, wow, luckily I ran into the `Duplicate keys of type SomeClass were found in a Dictionary` crash. That lead me to realize that SwiftUI is doing some fancy diffing stuff, and using the `==` operator of my class.

The operator wasn't used for actual equality in my code, but rather for just comparing a single field that I used in a `NavigationStack`. Lesson learned. Don't ever implement `==` if it doesn't signify true equality or you might run into really odd bugs later.

Comment: To add-on your answer, the reason `==` is used is because of `List(data, id: \.self)`. The list will only update if it see `data` changes. And since you used `id: \.self`, it will use `==(SomeClass, SomeClass)` to detect the changes.

Comment: Instead of removing your custom `==`, you might consider passing the actual changing part as the `id`, like `List(data, id: \.someProperty)`.

Comment: Two things. First of all, I had no idea that the equality operator had anything to do with this. Secondly, it is actually the @State that is causing the problem, **not** the list. Look at the printouts. I'm setting a value to X, but then the actual value stored is Y. Which was extremely baffling to me and hard to debug. Only later did I see that I myself defined X and Y as equal. I could see others running into this so I'll leave it up.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep that would not solve the problem in this case